# Cleveref with clrscode3e

Tags: cleveref, clrscode3e

I would like to make use of the advantages of the cleveref package also for pseudocode I write. More precisely, I am looking for a way to get the cleveref package to work with clrscode3e such that lines of code snippets can be referenced. To illustrate how exactly I would like to use the two packages in combination, I am providing a MWE down below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clrscode3e, cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{codebox} 
  \Procname{$\proc{MWE}$} 
  \li $x \gets 1$ \label{lin:assign}
  \End
\end{codebox}

As shown in \cref{lin:assign}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this way, the reference is not resolved. Interestingely, using `\ref` instead of `\cref` prints the correct line number. Is there a way to get this result with cleveref as well? I have tried defining a type with `\crefname`, but the counter is off: I have only gotten the `\cref` command to print the section number.

Comment: `cleveref` doesn't support `clrscode3e`. You could either try to figure out, how to patch `clrscode3e` to make it work (the code of both packages is nicely documented) or you use  `algorithmicx` (which is supported by `cleveref`) or you stick to plain `\ref`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clrscode3e` quite effectively disables cleveref (and hyperref too) by not using `\refstepcounter` by creating the label code itself.

You could define your own \label command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{clrscode3e}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{codelinenumber}{code}{code} %adapt
\newcommand\clrslabel[1]
 {\addtocounter{codelinenumber}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{codelinenumber}%
  \label{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{codebox}
  \Procname{$\proc{MWE}$}
  \li $x \gets 1$ \clrslabel{lin:assign}
  \End
\end{codebox}

As shown in \cref{lin:assign}, \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, if I use the `\clrslabel` command for multiple code boxes, referencing any but the first does not work correctly. For instance, if I label the second line of the second code box in my document, and subsequently reference the label, the line number is shown correctly, but the reference points to the first code box when clicking it. Any way of potentially fixing this?

Comment: You probably need a sensible definition of \theHcodelinenumber. But your original question didn't mention hyperref, so better ask a new question.